# include parameters file into pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is there any option to include parameters file (parameters.yml) with:

```
parameters: 
  - name: 'env'
    values:
      - 'DEV'
      - 'TST'
      - 'PROD'
```

into pipeline to achieve sth like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the  template  parameter can't achieve the same feature as Runtime Parameters.

The situation you expect needs to be achieved by runtime parameters.You need to repeat them in each pipeline you expect to have them.

Template Parameters unable to display the options in Pipeline run.

Template Parameters  supports defining values in the main yaml content to override the values in template parameters

For more detailed info, you can refer to the doc: [Template Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters) and [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script).